# FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR in copyTo method

Tags: android, phonegap

I try to copy file *new.js* if folder *file:///android_asset/www/js/* by the following code:

```
copyDir(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/js/');

function copyDir(copyTo) {
    try {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(copyTo,
    function(destinationDir) {
        alert('destinationDir.name: ' + destinationDir.name);

        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'newZip/new.js',
        function(file) {
            alert('file: ' + file.name);
            file.copyTo(destinationDir, "index_new.js", onResolveSuccess, onFail);
        },
        onFail);
    },
    onFail);
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
    }
}

function onResolveSuccess(fileEntry) {
    alert("Exist: " + fileEntry.name);
}

function onFail(error) {
     alert("Fail: " + error.code);
}
```

But I get the error with a code 1:

> Fail: 1

This error seems to be `FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR`.
But why do I get this error? 
If the string `alert('file: ' + file.name);` output is

> file: new.js

and that means that file *new.js* is for sure found...

Comment: If you are trying to copy *to* `file:///android_asset/www/js/`, that will not work, as that is not a directory. Assets are not files on the device. They are only files on your developer machine. On the device, they are merely read-only entries in the APK file.

Comment: @CommonsWare, but why "assets are not files on the device"?  If  `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL('file:///android_asset/www/js/', onResolveSuccess, onFail)` calls `onResolveSuccess`?

Comment: "why "assets are not files on the device"?" -- that is simply how assets work on Android. I do not know what `resolveLocalFileSystemURL()` is doing with `'file:///android_asset/www/‌​js/'`, as I am an Android expert, not a PhoneGap expert.